# How to prevent memory leak in code

Tags: c, opencv

I have called cvCreateStructuringElementEx() function (which returns IplConvKernel*) inside cvDilate function.

How can I prevent a memory leak if I have called cvDilate as given below ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  IplImage* topHatImg = cvLoadImage("ff.jpg",0);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
  {
    //memory leak due to repeated call to cvCreateStructuringElementEx()
    //how can I prevent this
    cvDilate(topHatImg, topHatImg,
             cvCreateStructuringElementEx(21, 3, 11, 2, CV_SHAPE_RECT,NULL ));
  }
}
```

Comment: c++11? Then `auto topHatImg(std::unique_ptr<IplImage>(cvLoadImage("ff.jpg",0));`

Comment: You could try using the C++ interface to OpenCV. This would take care of memory management for you. Otherwise tag this as C.

Comment: People downvote if: the question is to simple, to complex, to long, to short or simply they do not understand the problem :-) Forget about votes here! I wrote an answer, got 3 downvotes and the OP accepts the answer as solution. Simply forget the votes! We have wrong answers from 10k+ people and perfect solutions from beginners. Votes give only a trend, maybe :-)

Comment: Just create the element outside the loop! Your question sounds like: why the memory leak? `for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) { int *buffer = new int[42]; }

Comment: Didn't DV but tagging both `C` and `C++` is generally bad. The languages are different and may have different behaviour for the same code, and different solutions to the problem.

Comment: Somebody edited the post and tagged it as C++ ("because the code is C++"). Wrong..

Comment: this c++ code, but a am using c interface to opencv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either do as suggested in the comments or create the IplConvKernel structure out of the loop:

```
IplImage* topHatImg = cvLoadImage("ff.jpg",0);
IplConvKernel* convKernel = cvCreateStructuringElementEx(21, 3, 11, 2, CV_SHAPE_RECT,NULL );
for (size_t i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{      
  cvDilate(topHatImg, topHatImg,convKernel);
}
// deallocate stuff here
cvReleaseStructuringElement(&convKernel);
cvReleaseImage(&topHatImg);
// ...
```

I'll recommend you to switch to OpenCV C++ API.

Comment: My doubt was is there any other method other than this

Comment: +1 Well spotted. The trick is to call `cvReleaseStructuringElement()` to release the memory, but there's another way to use it in this scenario.

Comment: Hi @user_12 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 2):

**@KeillRandoris** gave the right answer. I apologize for adding another extremely similar answer but I wanted to talk a little bit more about the issue and share some code for better visualization.

As you identified in the question, the leak happens because `cvCreateStructuringElementEx()` allocates dynamic memory when called, which means that if you don't invoke `cvReleaseStructuringElement()` at every iteration to release that memory, the leak is going to happen:

```
IplImage* topHatImg = cvLoadImage("ff.jpg",0);
for (size_t i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{      
    IplConvKernel* element= cvCreateStructuringElementEx(21, 3, 11, 2, CV_SHAPE_RECT,NULL);
    cvDilate(topHatImg, topHatImg, element);
    cvReleaseStructuringElement(&element);
}

cvReleaseImage(&topHatImg);
```